# Open resource from HTML file

Tags: aptana

this might seem like a dumb question but I just don't get this to work with Aptana 3.

I installed the Aptana 3 plugins and Scala IDE into classic Eclipse 3.7.
Now in my HTML files there are links to resource files like CSS, JS, etc. I would like to be able to CTRL+click on such a link to open the file in another editor tab.

I just verified that Aptana 2 supports this without additional configuration.
Is this possible with version 3. If yes, what do I have to do in order to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you please file it?

Comment: Ingo, I created a ticket: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3632

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can tear me apart ;)
ctrl+shift+R then type resource file name

Comment: And on Mac it's CMD+Shift+R :)

Comment: Damn Torsten you have one point more than I have on stack overflow :P